# How to center view with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have universal app. Subview is rectangle which is positioned inside View.

How can I keep it centered and make it automatically adopt it's width depends on screen width ?

e.g. 
[image]

Comment: @Bhavin both cases are portrait. for example 1st case id iPad 2nd is iPhone5

Comment: @Bhavin yes, I need only portrait mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you want this only in portrait means its not an adaptive layout....So its fairly simple now....

As you want the width of object resize according to screen width... Just pinned right and left edges of screen to adopt width accordingly (or use equal width) 
As you not mention about height...so give fixed height to object....

And for making the object to the center of the view controller ....
Use center vertically and horizontally....and you are done..

Here is the image of what I said for better understanding

[image]

Comment: I will check later today and accept if it helps. I have no project next to me now

Comment: ok...no problemm...if you have any problem regarding to this...then let me know

Answer (score 1):

In order to center a view within it's superview, you need to check `Horizontal Center in Container` and `Vertical Center In container` in the Autolayout Align section:

[image]

You could also make use of [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) :

> With size classes, a storyboard or xib file can be used for any
>   available screen area. You build your interface as it will look in
>   most sizes, then update only the parts that need to change when the
>   available screen size changes.

Comment: I have no chance to check this now , I will check and if it works - I will accept answer, thank you